# Exp:resso Store Sample Checkout Template

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

I'm working with Exp-resso Store for ExpressionEngine for the first time and wondering if there are sample checkout templates available anywhere.

Comment: Um, who are you addressing here?

Comment: Hey Brett - this is not the right format for a question on StackOverflow ([see FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)). This kind of request should be sent directly to the support team for the specific add-on you're using (in this case, https://exp-resso.com/support).

Comment: @DerekHogue In this case it's not a real question and should be closed :)

Comment: Yo peoples. Sorry if I accidentally misused this. I'm excited about the EE stack overflow proposal but definitely still learning the ins and outs. 

And I appreciate the referral back to the Exp-resso Store support page, but they're actually directing support questions into Stack Overflow (in the hopes that folks will be able to answer support questions and build up their rep). 

Anyhow, Justin's answer(below) was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't even realize the install created example templates. I'm a donkey. I know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you have installed Store you can go to Design >> Template Manager >> store_examples template group and see a working example of an entire store. We have templates with the product, cart, and checkout tags all setup. You can also see these same templates if you open up system/expressionengine/third_party/store/templates.

If you have any other questions just let me know.